# Porque me da error al recorrer el array?

Tags: javascript

Me gustaria que me ayudara alguien a como recorrer el array, porque no me funciona?

```
var jsonObject = {
"hoteles": [
    {
        "viaje": {
            "origen": {
                "iataCode": "VL",
                "name": "Valencia",
                "base": false,
                "latitude": 39,4699,
                "longitude":  -0,376288,
                "country": {
                    "code": "sp",
                    "name": "España",
                    "seoName": "Valencia",
                    "englishSeoName": "spain",
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "url": "spain"
                }
            },
            "destino": {
                "iataCode": "BCN",
                "name": "Barcelona",
                "base": true,
                "latitude": 41,38506,
                "longitude": 2,17340,
                "country": {
                    "code": "sp",
                    "name": "España",
                    "seoName": "Spain",
                    "englishSeoName": "spain",
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "url": "spain"
                }
            },
            "price": {
                "value": "99.16",
                "valueMainUnit": "99",
                "valueFractionalUnit": "16",
                "currencySymbol": "€"
            },
            "dateFrom": "2015-02-02T00:00:00+00:00",
            "dateTo": "2015-04-02T00:00:00+01:00"
        }
    },
    {
        "viaje": {
            "origen": {
                "iataCode": "VL",
                "name": "Valencia",
                "base": false,
                "latitude": 39,4699,
                "longitude":  -0,376288,
                "country": {
                    "code": "sp",
                    "name": "España",
                    "seoName": "Valencia",
                    "englishSeoName": "spain",
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "url": "spain"
                }
            },
            "destino": {
                "iataCode": "BCN",
                "name": "Barcelona",
                "base": true,
                "latitude": 41,38506,
                "longitude": 2,17340,
                "country": {
                    "code": "sp",
                    "name": "España",
                    "seoName": "Spain",
                    "englishSeoName": "spain",
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "url": "spain"
                }
            },
            "price": {
                "value": "97.43",
                "valueMainUnit": "97",
                "valueFractionalUnit": "43",
                "currencySymbol": "€"
            },
            "dateFrom": "2015-02-02T00:00:00+00:00",
            "dateTo": "2015-04-02T00:00:00+01:00"
        }
    },
    {
        "viaje": {
            "origen": {
                "iataCode": "VL",
                "name": "Valencia",
                "base": false,
                "latitude": 39,4699,
                "longitude":  -0,376288,
                "country": {
                    "code": "sp",
                    "name": "España",
                    "seoName": "Valencia",
                    "englishSeoName": "spain",
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "url": "spain"
                }
            },
            "destino": {
                "iataCode": "BCN",
                "name": "Barcelona",
                "base": true,
                "latitude": 41,38506,
                "longitude": 2,17340,
                "country": {
                    "code": "sp",
                    "name": "España",
                    "seoName": "Spain",
                    "englishSeoName": "spain",
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "url": "spain"
                }
            },
            "price": {
                "value": "110.05",
                "valueMainUnit": "110",
                "valueFractionalUnit": "05",
                "currencySymbol": "€"
            },
            "dateFrom": "2015-02-02T00:00:00+00:00",
            "dateTo": "2015-04-02T00:00:00+01:00"
        }
    },
    {
        "viaje": {
            "origen": {
                "iataCode": "VL",
                "name": "Valencia",
                "base": false,
                "latitude": 39,4699,
                "longitude":  -0,376288,
                "country": {
                    "code": "sp",
                    "name": "España",
                    "seoName": "Valencia",
                    "englishSeoName": "spain",
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "url": "spain"
                }
            },
            "destino": {
                "iataCode": "BCN",
                "name": "Barcelona",
                "base": true,
                "latitude": 41,38506,
                "longitude": 2,17340,
                "country": {
                    "code": "sp",
                    "name": "España",
                    "seoName": "Spain",
                    "englishSeoName": "spain",
                    "currency": "EUR",
                    "url": "spain"
                }
            },
            "price": {
                "value": "102.21",
                "valueMainUnit": "102",
                "valueFractionalUnit": "21",
                "currencySymbol": "€"
            },
            "dateFrom": "2015-02-02T00:00:00+00:00",
            "dateTo": "2015-04-02T00:00:00+01:00"
        }
    }],

    "count":4,
    "totalCount":4,
    "currency":{"symbol":"€","maxPrice":"150","defaultPrice":0},
    "currencySymbol":"€",
    "request":{"from":"VL","to":"BCN","start_date":"2015-02-02","end_date":"2015-04-02","max_price":"500"}

};
/////
```

He intentado recorrerlo con este código:

```
   for (var i=0; i< jsonObject.hoteles.length; i++){
                //Para obtener el objeto de tu lista
                var hotel = jsonObject.hoteles[i];
                document.write(hotel.viaje.origen.name);
        }
```

Comment: hacer el bucle for que se ve en el codigo abajo.

Comment: Un truco para solucionar muchos problemas en JavaScript/JSON que te va a salvar mucho tiempo y dolores de cabeza: **mira la consola de JavaScript en el navegador**. El problema planteado en esta pregunta se podría haber solucionado de ese modo en cuestión de segundos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el JSON, en los valores "latitude" y "longitude" estás usando como separador decimal una coma y debe ser un punto.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un pequeño error de sintaxis en latitude y longitude debería de quedar de esta manera:

```
  var jsonObject = {
  "hoteles": [{
      "viaje": {
          "origen": {
              "iataCode": "VL",
              "name": "Valencia",
              "base": false,
              "latitude": 39.4699, //"latitude": 39, 4699, <- error de sintaxis 
              "longitude": -0.376288,
              "country": {
                  "code": "sp",
                  "name": "España",
                  "seoName": "Valencia",
                  "englishSeoName": "spain",
                  "currency": "EUR",
                  "url": "spain"
              }
          },
          "destino": {
              "iataCode": "BCN",
              "name": "Barcelona",
              "base": true,
              "latitude": 41.38506,
              "longitude": 2.17340,
              "country": {
                  "code": "sp",
                  "name": "España",
                  "seoName": "Spain",
                  "englishSeoName": "spain",
                  "currency": "EUR",
                  "url": "spain"
              }
          },
          "price": {
              "value": "99.16",
              "valueMainUnit": "99",
              "valueFractionalUnit": "16",
              "currencySymbol": "€"
          },
          "dateFrom": "2015-02-02T00:00:00+00:00",
          "dateTo": "2015-04-02T00:00:00+01:00"
      }
  }, {
      "viaje": {
          "origen": {
              "iataCode": "VL",
              "name": "Valencia",
              "base": false,
              "latitude": 39.4699,
              "longitude": -0.376288,
              "country": {
                  "code": "sp",
                  "name": "España",
                  "seoName": "Valencia",
                  "englishSeoName": "spain",
                  "currency": "EUR",
                  "url": "spain"
              }
          },
          "destino": {
              "iataCode": "BCN",
              "name": "Barcelona",
              "base": true,
              "latitude": 41.38506,
              "longitude": 2.17340,
              "country": {
                  "code": "sp",
                  "name": "España",
                  "seoName": "Spain",
                  "englishSeoName": "spain",
                  "currency": "EUR",
                  "url": "spain"
              }
          },
          "price": {
              "value": "97.43",
              "valueMainUnit": "97",
              "valueFractionalUnit": "43",
              "currencySymbol": "€"
          },
          "dateFrom": "2015-02-02T00:00:00+00:00",
          "dateTo": "2015-04-02T00:00:00+01:00"
      }
  }, {
      "viaje": {
          "origen": {
              "iataCode": "VL",
              "name": "Valencia",
              "base": false,
              "latitude": 39.4699,
              "longitude": -0.376288,
              "country": {
                  "code": "sp",
                  "name": "España",
                  "seoName": "Valencia",
                  "englishSeoName": "spain",
                  "currency": "EUR",
                  "url": "spain"
              }
          },
          "destino": {
              "iataCode": "BCN",
              "name": "Barcelona",
              "base": true,
              "latitude": 41.38506,
              "longitude": 2.17340,
              "country": {
                  "code": "sp",
                  "name": "España",
                  "seoName": "Spain",
                  "englishSeoName": "spain",
                  "currency": "EUR",
                  "url": "spain"
              }
          },
          "price": {
              "value": "110.05",
              "valueMainUnit": "110",
              "valueFractionalUnit": "05",
              "currencySymbol": "€"
          },
          "dateFrom": "2015-02-02T00:00:00+00:00",
          "dateTo": "2015-04-02T00:00:00+01:00"
      }
  }, {
      "viaje": {
          "origen": {
              "iataCode": "VL",
              "name": "Valencia",
              "base": false,
              "latitude": 39.4699,
              "longitude": -0.376288,
              "country": {
                  "code": "sp",
                  "name": "España",
                  "seoName": "Valencia",
                  "englishSeoName": "spain",
                  "currency": "EUR",
                  "url": "spain"
              }
          },
          "destino": {
              "iataCode": "BCN",
              "name": "Barcelona",
              "base": true,
              "latitude": 41.38506,
              "longitude": 2.17340,
              "country": {
                  "code": "sp",
                  "name": "España",
                  "seoName": "Spain",
                  "englishSeoName": "spain",
                  "currency": "EUR",
                  "url": "spain"
              }
          },
          "price": {
              "value": "102.21",
              "valueMainUnit": "102",
              "valueFractionalUnit": "21",
              "currencySymbol": "€"
          },
          "dateFrom": "2015-02-02T00:00:00+00:00",
          "dateTo": "2015-04-02T00:00:00+01:00"
      }
  }],
  "count": 4,
  "totalCount": 4,
  "currency": {
      "symbol": "€",
      "maxPrice": "150",
      "defaultPrice": 0
  },
  "currencySymbol": "€",
  "request": {
      "from": "VL",
      "to": "BCN",
      "start_date": "2015-02-02",
      "end_date": "2015-04-02",
      "max_price": "500"
  };
```

Comment: Los valores de `latitude` y `longitude` no son un arreglo, son valores numéricos. Tu solución no funcionará.

Comment: en este caso si no quieres manejarlo como array podrías usarlo como string "latitude": "39, 4699", el error básicamente es que no tiene una sintaxis correcta si lo requiere manejar como array o como string ya seria el caso del requerimiento con el que se este trabajando

Comment: Si, tienes razón cuando dices que el problema es que no tiene la sintáxis  correcta pero las dos propuestas que haces son incorrectas también. Los valores de `latitud` y `longitud` son números flotantes no arreglos de las partes de un número. En caso que uses una cadena de caracteres, en javascript el único separador decimal válido es el `.` por lo que esa segunda solución `"latitude": "39, 4699"` no funcionará de todas formas.